# OpenCL clEnqueueMapBuffer buffer cleanup

Tags: opencl

Is it possible to release host memory created by `clEnqueueMapBuffer`?

For example, create a buffer and map host memory:

```c
  cl_mem buffer = clCreateBuffer(...);
  float* dataPtr = (float*)clEnqueueMapBuffer(...,buffer,...);
```

Do some OpenCL stuff, then cleanup:

```c
  clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(...,buffer,(void *)dataPtr,...);
  clReleaseMemObject(buffer);
```

However, at this point the `dataPtr` is not null. How do you release the memory on the host allocated by `clEnqueueMapBuffer`? Delete and free don't work and I can find nothing in OpenCL documentation that provides a means to release the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, clEnqueueMapBuffer doesn't actually allocate any memory *as such*, but maps a certain address range on the host to look like host memory but actually be referring to device memory. This means that it doesn't need deallocating as there was never any memory allocated in the first place (new/malloc style) by clEnqueueMapBuffer

Comment: James, thanks for your input.  I went ahead and did a little computing experiment to see what was actually happening in physical memory on the host.  It turns out that clEnqueueMapBuffer is actually allocating memory.  It also turns out that clEnqueueUnmapMemObject is in fact releasing that memory and just not setting the pointer to null.

Comment: Is it actually allocating memory, or is it just reserving some of the virtual memory space which might look like memory allocation?

Comment: It is actually allocating memory.  Using the task manager in windows I was able track the amount of physical memory usage every time I created a map buffer.  There is nothing special about a float* that would allow it to write directly to device memory.  In fact, you are required to call clEnqueueWriteBuffer before the host buffer is transferred to the device.

Comment: the pointer is just a variable, nobody is going to set it to null for you. likewise, "void *p = malloc(10); free(p);" isn't going to set p to null.

Comment: To answer the question, you'd don't need to manage the memory that map gives you.